# custom actionbar with height how to set background to full screen

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-background

do you know how can i set full screen background color (i need it when application start) when i have custom actionbar with 120dp height in theme. 
My actionbar style:

```
  <style name="MyActionBar"
     parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
   <item name="android:height">120dp</item>
   <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
   <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
  </style>
```

I want to set something like full screen color background "behind" this actionbar. This style have transparent background so if i could set some color behind it will look as i want, but i don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution for my issue. I have to create splash screen to get what i want. 
If anyone have similar problem so shoud create splash screen.
To done this you have to:

1. Creating a drawable resource for the splash screen.
2. Defining a new theme that will display the drawable resource.
3. Adding a new Activity to the application that will be used as the splash screen defined by the theme created in the previous step.

Here is a simple example how to do this: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines before setContentView

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then I believe you mean the main background colour of the activity, as you say 'behind' the action bar.

In the XML for your activity you should see something similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >
```

If you append `android:backgroundColor="#000"` then you should get the result you're looking for (of course please replace #000 with the colour of your choice).

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:backgroundColor="#000" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout's background color like this:

```
 getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_color,null));
```

You should define `background_color` in color.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="background_color">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for answers guys, but i think i poorly explained my problem.

So look on this image

[image]

When application loading i can set in my theme style background color and this color is only for place in actionbar(120dp like in style), but i want to have color or image background on fullscreen when application loading.

And i don't know how is set this white background when application is loading.

When i set in my style theme for actionbar background to transparent the color is the same as on the rest of screen, and that's why i thought that when i change this white color "behind" and set action bar background to transparent it will work as i want to.

I hope that now i explain clearly what i trying to do. I want to set background to whole screen when aplication loading.